# The method is not allowed for the requested URL - Flask + HTML

Tags: python, flask

I am getting the message "The method is not allowed for the requested URL" on my html page. I know the problem is with POST method but can't find that out.

My program is to list out the entries in one session.

PYTHON:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session
from flask_session import Session

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

notes = []

@app.route("/", methods=["GET","POST"])
def index():
    if request.method == "POST":
        note = request.form.get("note")
        notes.append(note)


    return render_template("index.html", notes=notes)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```

HTML:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block heading %}
  NOTES
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

<ul>
    {% for note in notes %}
        <li>{{ note }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

<form action="{{ url_for('index') }}" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="note" placeholder="Type Here">
    <button>Add Note</button>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

I want a list of entries but getting the error - The method is not allowed for the requested URL.

Comment: Does the `GET` request work?

Comment: Can you show the full error?

Comment: Try adding `type='submit'` to the form button?

Comment: Sam Hollenbach, thanks, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Adding
    Type = '' submit''
Worked for me